# React enzyme reducer test, TypeError: (0 , _PlanReducer.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to test my reducer is returning values or not using simple test cases but getting the error that says its not a function. Writing the code and exact error below

```js
describe('Plan Reducer', ()=>{
    it('Should return default state', () => {
        const newState = PlanReducer(undefined,{});
        expect(newState).toEqual([]);
    });

    it('Should return new state if recieving type', () => {
        const plans = [{title: 'Plan 1'}, {title: 'Plan 2'}];
        const newState = PlanReducer(undefined, {
            type: constant.FETCH_ALL_PLANS,
            payload: plans
        })
        expect(newState).toEqual(plans)
    })
```

but getting error saying TypeError: (0 , _PlanReducer.default) is not a function
Here is my reducer set up:

```js
const initialState = {
    plans:[],
    planHistory:null,
    currentplan:null,
    transactions:[]
   };
   
   export const PlanReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
      case constant.FETCH_ALL_PLANS:
        return {
            ...state,
            plans: [...action.payload.plansData]
        };
      case constant.CURRENT_PLAN:
        console.log(action.payload)
        return {
            ...state,
            currentplan: action.payload.currentsubscriptions[0],
            planHistory: action.payload.subscriptions
        };
      case constant.FETCH_TRANSACTION:
        console.log(action.payload)
        return {
            ...state,
            transactions: [...action.payload.transaction]
          };
         //default
       default:
         return state;
     }
   }
```

Comment: How did you export and import the reducer module?

Comment: This was resolved. Yes it was an issue in export